# Making a MySQL query with JOIN in UPDATE work with SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm working with a frontend that supports both MySQL and SQLite.

However, one of the queries that I'm running has JOINs in the UPDATE part. Upon Googling, this isn't supported in SQLite.

The query is this:

```
UPDATE playertimes t
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT MIN(time) mintime,
          MAP,
          track,
          style
   FROM playertimes
   GROUP BY MAP,
            track,
            style) minjoin ON t.time = minjoin.mintime
AND t.MAP = minjoin.MAP
AND t.track = minjoin.track
AND t.style = minjoin.style
JOIN
  (SELECT ((50.0 * 2) * 1.5) points) best
JOIN
  (SELECT (COUNT(*) * (2 / 10.0)) points,
                                  MAP,
                                  track,
                                  style
   FROM playertimes
   GROUP BY MAP,
            track,
            style) additive ON t.MAP = additive.MAP
AND t.track = additive.track
AND t.style = additive.style
JOIN
  (SELECT MIN(time) lowest, (MIN(time) / 15.0) points,
                                               MAP,
                                               track,
                                               style
   FROM playertimes
   GROUP BY MAP,
            track,
            style) FINAL ON t.MAP = FINAL.MAP
AND t.track = FINAL.track
AND t.style = FINAL.style
JOIN
  (SELECT (1.0) style, (1.0) track) multipliers
SET t.points = (CASE
                    WHEN minjoin.mintime IS NOT NULL THEN (((best.points + additive.points + FINAL.points) * multipliers.style) * multipliers.track)
                    ELSE (((((best.points + additive.points + FINAL.points) * multipliers.style) * multipliers.track) * (FINAL.lowest / t.time)) * 0.85)
                END)
WHERE t.MAP = 'bhop_atom'
  AND t.track = 0
  AND t.style = 0;
```

Error:

```
near "t": syntax error
```

(I know that it some parts like the `multipliers` selection look like they make no sense to do at SQL level, but I plan on changing those to be dynamic soon. Some of those parts actually are replaced with variables in my frontend.)

My goal is to get this query's final results done in only one initial query (subqueries are fine). How can I achieve it? It's fine if the final query is incompatible with MySQL as I'm making the application send different queries for MySQL or SQLite in case they are incompatible.

Note: The results are exactly like I want them to be when this query runs on MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

Using constant values as separate joins is cumbersome; I've made them [parameters](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#varparam).

The UPDATE statement itself must use only a single table (without an alias); you have to look up the new values with a [correlated subquery](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#cosub).

Let's move all those subqueries away into [common table expressions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html).

That outer join is used only to check whether a rows exists; I'd rather use EXISTS for that. (But using an outer join might save some typing.)

```
WITH minjoin AS (
  SELECT MIN(time) AS mintime,
         MAP,
         track,
         style
  FROM playertimes
  GROUP BY MAP,
           track,
           style
),
additive AS (
  SELECT COUNT(*) * (2 / 10.0) AS points,
         MAP,
         track,
         style
  FROM playertimes
  GROUP BY MAP,
           track,
           style
),
FINAL AS (
  SELECT MIN(time) AS lowest,
         MIN(time) / 15.0 AS points,
         MAP,
         track,
         style
  FROM playertimes
  GROUP BY MAP,
           track,
           style
)
UPDATE playertimes
SET points = (SELECT (:BestPoints + additive.points + FINAL.points) *
                     :MultipliersStyle * :MultipliersTrack *
                     CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT *
                                       FROM minjoin
                                       WHERE mintime = playertimes.time
                                         AND MAP     = playertimes.MAP
                                         AND track   = playertimes.track
                                         AND style   = playertimes.style)
                          THEN 1
                          ELSE FINAL.lowest / t.time * 0.85
                     END
              FROM playertimes AS t
              JOIN additive USING (MAP, track, style)
              JOIN FINAL    USING (MAP, track, style)
              WHERE MAP   = playertimes.MAP
                AND track = playertimes.track
                AND style = playertimes.style
             )
WHERE MAP   = 'bhop_atom'
  AND track = 0
  AND style = 0;
```

Answer (score -1):

SQLite does not support alias in the update statement. Do try using the script without aliases. Where ever you have the alias "t", try replacing it with "playertimes" as follow:

```
AND playertimes.track = additive.track
AND playertimes.style = additive.style
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it isn't the case. `near "LEFT": syntax error`